# JPA native query returning byte array instead of string when using concat()

Tags: java, mysql, string, jpa, arrays

I am using Play Framework, JPA and MySQL, but I am having some issues with the`concat()` function in an SQL query. When I used it in my MySQL GUI it outputs the correct value of the concatenated columns, but when I used it with JPA in my code, it returns `byte[]`, i.e. a byte array.

My entity:

```
@Entity
public class NumberData{

    @javax.persistence.Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long Id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private Long numbr;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String somekey;

}
```

My select query:

```
String query="SELECT concat(somekey,id) as uid,numbr from numberdata";
List<Object[]> numList = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

But when I try to print it it gave me a byte array:

```
for (Object[] ob : numList) {
    Logger.info("output "+ob[0]+"");    //output [B@48927
}
```

I know I can do `new String(ob[0])` to convert it to string, but since the MySQL GUI gave me the correct result, is this a problem with JPA? How can I get a string (varchar) directly from the MySQL query?

Comment: how can it be a problem in JPA ? JPA native query simply passes your query through JDBC, hence you are datastore dependent, and get what the JDBC driver gives you ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer can be found in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for `CONCAT`:

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings, the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string.

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) part of the JDBC documentation hints that `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` are converted to `byte[]` if it is a binary string:

> java.lang.String (unless the character set for the column is BINARY, then byte[] is returned.

As proposed in the first link above, a cast of the non-string argument should solve the problem:

> `SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);`

In your case, it would look like this:

```
String query= "SELECT concat(somekey,CAST(id AS CHAR)) as uid,numbr from numberdata";
```